# Menu Javascript nivel 2/4 com erro

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, dropdown

Como faço para definir o mesmo código, com variáveis diferentes, mas para executar a mesma ação.

Eu tentei re-escrevê-lo e mesmo assim, o `Javascript` está com erro, no caso seria um menu em dropdown, com até 4 níveis, ainda estou no 2° nível dele, que ao clicar fora do menu, o mesmo fecha

**Caso o usuário clique fora do menu, o mesmo fechará**

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i=0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Quando o usuário clicar no botão, alterna entre
esconder e mostrar o conteúdo '*Dropdown*'**

```
/*Primários*/

    function funcaoPrincipais() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    /*Secundários*/
    function  funcaoPrincipaisPrincipal() {
        document.getElementById("myFirstSubForPrincipal").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    function  funcaoPrincipaisInstitucional() {
        document.getElementById("myFirstSubForInstitucional").classList.toggle("show");
    }
```

Comment: Podes fazer um jsFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xakkbvn5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vê se este código lhe ajuda.

```html
<head>
<style>
body {margin:25px; font:11px Verdana,Arial; background:#eee}
ul.menu {list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0}
ul.menu * {margin:0; padding:0}
ul.menu a {display:block; color:#000; text-decoration:none}
ul.menu li {position:relative; float:left; margin-right:2px}
ul.menu ul {position:absolute; top:26px; left:0; background:#d1d1d1; display:none; opacity:0; list-style:none}
ul.menu ul li {position:relative; border:1px solid #aaa; border-top:none; width:148px; margin:0}
ul.menu ul li a {display:block; padding:3px 7px 5px; background-color:#d1d1d1}
ul.menu ul li a:hover {background-color:#c5c5c5}
ul.menu ul ul {left:148px; top:-1px}
ul.menu .menulink {border:1px solid #aaa; padding:5px 7px 7px; font-weight:bold; width:134px}
ul.menu .sub {background:#d1d1d1; }
ul.menu .topline {border-top:1px solid #aaa}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var menu=function(){
 var t=15,z=50,s=6,a;
 function dd(n){this.n=n; this.h=[]; this.c=[]}
 dd.prototype.init=function(p,c){
  a=c; var w=document.getElementById(p), s=w.getElementsByTagName('ul'), l=s.length, i=0;
  for(i;i<l;i++){
   var h=s[i].parentNode; this.h[i]=h; this.c[i]=s[i];
   h.onmouseover=new Function(this.n+'.st('+i+',true)');
   h.onmouseout=new Function(this.n+'.st('+i+')');
  }
 }
 dd.prototype.st=function(x,f){
  var c=this.c[x], h=this.h[x], p=h.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
  clearInterval(c.t); c.style.overflow='hidden';
  if(f){
   p.className+=' '+a;
   if(!c.mh){c.style.display='block'; c.style.height=''; c.mh=c.offsetHeight; c.style.height=0}
   if(c.mh==c.offsetHeight){c.style.overflow='visible'}
   else{c.style.zIndex=z; z++; c.t=setInterval(function(){sl(c,1)},t)}
  }else{p.className=p.className.replace(a,''); c.t=setInterval(function(){sl(c,-1)},t)}
 }
 function sl(c,f){
  var h=c.offsetHeight;
  if((h<=0&&f!=1)||(h>=c.mh&&f==1)){
   if(f==1){c.style.filter=''; c.style.opacity=1; c.style.overflow='visible'}
   clearInterval(c.t); return
  }
  var d=(f==1)?Math.ceil((c.mh-h)/s):Math.ceil(h/s), o=h/c.mh;
  c.style.opacity=o; c.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+(o*100)+')';
  c.style.height=h+(d*f)+'px'
 }
 return{dd:dd}
}();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="menu" id="menu">
 <li><a href="#" class="menulink">Dropdown 1>></a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Navigation Item 1</a></li>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="sub">Navigation Item 2</a>
    <ul>
     <li class="topline"><a href="#">Navigation Item 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Navigation Item 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Navigation Item 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Navigation Item 4</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Navigation Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="sub">Navigation Item 3>></a>
    <ul>
     <li class="topline"><a href="#">Navigation Item 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Navigation Item 2</a></li>
     <li>
      <a href="#" class="sub">Navigation Item 3>></a>
      <ul>
       <li class="topline"><a href="#">Navigation Item 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Navigation Item 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Navigation Item 3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Navigation Item 4</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Navigation Item 5</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Navigation Item 6</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Navigation Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Navigation Item 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Navigation Item 5</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
 var menu=new menu.dd("menu");
 menu.init("menu","menuhover");
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: é ótimo mas ainda assim não é o que preciso, preciso de um menu clicável, e que, quando você clique em outra opção, a anterior esconda e a atual mostre... ainda to tentando aqui, procurando tutoriais, mas não encontrei nada ;-;